# Why aren't my equations centered?

Tags: align

The equations produced by this code are centered

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
    & \mathclap{f: A \to B, g: B \to C} \label{eq:1}
    \\
    f(a) &= \ldots \label{eq:2}
    \\
    g(b) &= \ldots \label{eq:3}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

whereas these are no longer centered. Equation 1 is not centered like how normal humans would center it. Why is this so? Or is that considered centered for latex?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
    \mathclap{\alpha_{s,j}^t = g(\frac{e^{\varphi_{c}([h_j^t,l_j,s])}}{\sum_j e^{\varphi_{c}([h_j^t,l_j,s])}}) \quad \hat{x}_{\varphi}^{t} = \varphi_m([h_i^t,l_i,s])} \label{eq:1}
    \\
    \hat{x}_i^{'t} &= \hat{x}_{\varphi}^{t} + (1 - \alpha_{l,i}^t)\hat{x}_i^{t-1} \label{eq:left}
    \\
    \hat{x}_i^{t} &= \hat{x}_{\varphi}^{t} + (1 - \alpha_{r,i}^t)\hat{x}_i^{'t} \label{eq:right}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

This is how I would like the equations to be but without using two align environments due to the added space.

```
\begin{align}
    \alpha_{s,j}^t = g(\frac{e^{\varphi_{c}([h_j^t,l_j,s])}}{\sum_j e^{\varphi_{c}([h_j^t,l_j,s])}}) \quad \hat{x}_{\varphi}^{t} = \varphi_m([h_i^t,l_i,s]) \label{eq:1}
\end{align}
\begin{align}
    \hat{x}_i^{'t} &= \hat{x}_{\varphi}^{t} + (1 - \alpha_{l,i}^t)\hat{x}_i^{t-1} \label{eq:left}
    \\
    \hat{x}_i^{t} &= \hat{x}_{\varphi}^{t} + (1 - \alpha_{r,i}^t)\hat{x}_i^{'t} \label{eq:right}
\end{align}
```

[image]

Comment: you used `\mathclap` whose only function is to hide the size of the expression, so tex has no information about the first row size

Comment: @DavidCarlisle thank you. How do I provide it information about the first row size? I would essentially like it to be like 2 align environments but without the added space like in my edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

you used `\mathclap` whose only function is to hide the size of the expression, so tex has no information about the first row size

I would use a normal `equation` for the first row

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\begin{document}

\noindent X\dotfill X
\begin{equation}
    \alpha_{s,j}^t = g\biggl(\frac{e^{\varphi_{c}([h_j^t,l_j,s])}}{\sum_j e^{\varphi_{c}([h_j^t,l_j,s])}}\biggr) 
   \quad \hat{x}_{\varphi}^{t} = \varphi_m([h_i^t,l_i,s]) \label{eq:1}  
\end{equation}
\nopagebreak\vspace{-\baselineskip}
\begin{align}
    \hat{x}_i^{'t} &= \hat{x}_{\varphi}^{t} + (1 - \alpha_{l,i}^t)\hat{x}_i^{t-1} \label{eq:left}
    \\
    \hat{x}_i^{t} &= \hat{x}_{\varphi}^{t} + (1 - \alpha_{r,i}^t)\hat{x}_i^{'t} \label{eq:right} 
\end{align}
\noindent X\dotfill X
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could encase an `align` environment inside a `gather` environment.

I would also suggest you use `\exp(...)` notation instead of `e^{...}` notation in the first row; it doesn't require a lot of extra space, but it does improve the legibility.

Separately, might `\hat{x}_i^{'t}` better be written as `\hat{x}_i^{\prime t}`?

The framelines at the edges of the following screenshot are drawn because the sample code loads the `showframe` package. You may omit `\usepackage{showframe}` in your real document.

[image]

Remark: You may safely ignore the following sequence of error messages:

```
! Package amsmath Error: Multiple \label's: label 'eq:right' will be lost.

See the amsmath package documentation for explanation.
```

The user guide of the `amsmath` package states explicitly that it's ok to nest an `align` environment inside a `gather` environment. Creating cross-references to the second and third equation via, say `\eqref` will work just fine.

---

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}   % for 'gather' and 'align' environments
\usepackage{showframe} % draw framelines around textblock
\begin{document}

\begin{gather}
\alpha_{s,j}^t = 
   g\biggl(\frac{\exp\{\varphi_{c}([h_j^t,l_j,s])\}}{%
     \sum_j \exp\{\varphi_{c}([h_j^t,l_j,s])\}}
     \biggr) 
     \quad 
     \hat{x}_{\varphi}^{t} = \varphi_m([h_i^t,l_i,s]) 
     \label{eq:1} \\
\begin{align}
   \hat{x}_i^{\prime t} &= \hat{x}_{\varphi}^{t} 
     + (1 - \alpha_{l,i}^t)\hat{x}_i^{t-1}
     \label{eq:left} 
   \\[\jot]
   \hat{x}_i^{t} &= \hat{x}_{\varphi}^{t} 
     + (1 - \alpha_{r,i}^t)\hat{x}_i^{\prime t}
     \label{eq:right}
\end{align}
\end{gather}

\end{document}
```